# How to define the atom numbers in unsaturated hydrocarbons correctly according to IUPAC?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature, hydrocarbons

I would like to address the compound below.

[image]

This compound on elaborate elongation would result in this structure.

[image]

But is the below given numbering correct? I am just wondering that what if the same compound is given numbering, starting from that carbon which is assigned 7th number in the first elaborate diagram (second diagram), by doing so, triple bonded substituent will also get the least number, as shown in the below given diagram.

[image]

---

I have a similar problem with this compound:

[image]

What if you just reverse the numbering? By reversal I mean, the carbon assigned 1st number should be given the last number, am I violating any rule? If I do that, by numbering the compound in reverse order, we get least number for the methyl chain substituent, so is it necessary that methyl group substituted in the side chain should get the highest possible number?

In short, I mean, is the below given numbering valid or not?

[image]

Comment: I think your numbering is correct.  Your choice is between including the 6-alkene or 6-alkyne in the main chain.  The rule is "tie goes to the alkene".  This link may provide useful examples starting around p. 9  http://www.csupomona.edu/~psbeauchamp/pdf/314_supp_8_nomen_2.pdf

Comment: @ron yes, i agree, but what if i start the numbering from the number seventh carbon?, is that valid too?

Comment: No, see page 5, item 7, "middle" example in the link I supplied. P.S. Good to see you again, hope things are going well.

Comment: @ron yeah, i was busy in my exams, and i am fine, but ron  i didn't found any clue in that example, it seems to be the same case as the compound i have exampled, but why is the numbering assigned as such, what if i just reverse the numbering, am i violating any rule if i reverse it?

Comment: Note how in the example I mentioned above (6-ethyl-6-methylocta-trans-2-cis-4,7-triene) they do not start numbering from the side with the terminal double bond, but rather from the side with the lowest overall double bond numbers.

Comment: @ron hurrah!, i got it, thanks ron, i have got my doubt cleared now, but what about the 2nd example in my question, which contains no double bond, i have given two structures with different numberings, which one should i consider to be correct?

Comment: the first one, it has the lower substituent numbering (1,4 vs. 2,5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first structure, I think your numbering is correct. Your choice is between including the 6-alkene or 6-alkyne in the main chain. The rule is "tie goes to the alkene".  [This link](http://www.cpp.edu/~psbeauchamp/pdf/314_supp_8_nomen_2.pdf) may provide useful examples starting around p. 9.  Also see  page 5, item 7, "middle" example in the above link for another relevant example. Note how in this example (6-ethyl-6-methylocta-trans-2-cis-4,7-triene) they do not start numbering from the side with the terminal double bond, but rather from the side with the lowest overall double bond numbers.

In your second compound, your first numbering scheme has the lower substituent numbering (1,4 vs. 2,5).

Comment: Please note that your link contains several mistakes. In particular, the numbering in the following examples is wrong: 4-methyl-1-ethylidenecyclohexane should be 1-ethylidene-4-methylcyclohexane, 6-methyl-3-methylenecyclohex-1-ene should be 3-methyl-6-methylidenecyclohex-1-ene, 1-methyl-3-(4-methylpent-3-ynyl)cyclohexa-1,3-diene should be 1-methyl-3-(4-methylpent-2-yn-1-yl)cyclohexa-1,3-diene, 4-(2,2-dimethylcycloprop-1-enyl)-6-isopropylcyclooct-1-yne should be 4-(3,3-dimethylcycloprop-1-en-1-yl)-6-(propan-2-yl)cyclooct-1-yne, 4,4-dimethylnon-8-en-1-yne should be 6,6-dimethylnon-1-en-8-yne, …

Comment: … 5-(but-2E-enyl)nona-5Z,7E-dien-1-yne should be (2E,4Z,7E)-5-(but-3-yn-1-yl)nona-2,4,7-triene, and 2-(1-methylpropyl)pent-1-en-3-yne should be 5-methyl-4-methylidenehept-2-yne.

Answer (score 2):

Your first compound should be (3E)-5-ethynylhepta-1,3,6-triene. The 2 conjugated double bonds at the end determine the first carbon.

The second compound should be (4-methylpentyl)cyclobutane. The aliphatic group has less precedence than the cyclobutane group.